# WPF - reusable DataTemplate for ItemsControl/ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, datatemplate, itemscontrol

I need to reuse the following DataTemplate:

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="courseItemTemplate">
        <Border BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="5">
            <Border.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush>
                    <SolidColorBrush.Color>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CourseColorConverter}">
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}" Path="DataContext.CourseColors"/>
                            <Binding Path="Course.CourseInfo.ID"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </SolidColorBrush.Color>
                </SolidColorBrush>
            </Border.Background>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"/>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
```

The template will serve both ListBox and an ItemsControl, with different ItemsSource, and different template for presenting the content of each item.
Essentially, what I would like is to be able to replace the ContentControl tag, with the relevant template for each of the controls

Comment: What's so bad about two different templates? You may make the SolidColorBrush a resource.

Comment: what if I want the change the style of the border? I'd have to change it in 2 places if I want both borders to be styled the same

Comment: That Style could obviously also be a resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two DataTemplates with a common Border Style:

```
<Style x:Key="BorderStyle" TargetType="Border">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush>...</SolidColorBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<DataTemplate x:Key="T1">
    <Border Style="{StaticResource BorderStyle}">
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding P1}"/>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="T2">
    <Border Style="{StaticResource BorderStyle}">
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding P2}"/>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```